# How to alter default ajax_view default ScrollTop?

Tags: views, ajax, javascript

In `ajax_view.js`, the code responsible of smooth Ajax View ScrollTop when changing the exposed filters is the following :

```
Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.viewsScrollTop = function (ajax, response, status) {
  // Scroll to the top of the view. This will allow users
  // to browse newly loaded content after e.g. clicking a pager
  // link.
  var offset = $(response.selector).offset();
  // We can't guarantee that the scrollable object should be
  // the body, as the view could be embedded in something
  // more complex such as a modal popup. Recurse up the DOM
  // and scroll the first element that has a non-zero top.
  var scrollTarget = response.selector;
  while ($(scrollTarget).scrollTop() == 0 && $(scrollTarget).parent()) {
    scrollTarget = $(scrollTarget).parent();
  }
  // Only scroll upward
  if (offset.top - 100 < $(scrollTarget).scrollTop()) {
    $(scrollTarget).animate({scrollTop: (offset.top - 10)}, 500);
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

I tried to alter this behaviour from a custom module, but no way to get it working. How can I proper change the values of `offset.top - 10` to `offset.top - 100` ? Here's one of my several tries...

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  drupal_add_js( drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME').'/assets/js/MYSCRIPT.js');
  //...

//IN MYSCRIPT.js
Drupal.behaviors.events = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
    $('.my_view', context).ajaxStart(function(){
      $('.my_view', context).fadeTo(500, 0.7);//this works
    });
    $('.my_view', context).ajaxSuccess(function(){
      $('.my_view', context).fadeTo(300, 1)//this works
          .animate({scrollTop: (offset.top - 100)}, 500);//this doesn't
  //...
```

Comment: It's javascript so copy/paste the whole `Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.viewsScrollTop` declaration into your own JS file, and change the value. Voila, you've just monkey-patched an un-extendable function.

Comment: Hey Clive, a long time... Thank you. I tried that, but it only works if I cut and paste, not copy and paste. Views code is run after mine... My module's name is vts_commerce, so I believe it acts after views if alphabetic order ?

Comment: It's more about what order the JS comes out in...try adding a high `weight` to the script you're adding (example in [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Clive comments, I solved it

- copying the whole `Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.viewsScrollTop` in my js script
- editing that copy with my own values
- adding a heavy weight to that script :

  ```
  function MYMODULE_init() {
    drupal_add_js( drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME').'/assets/js/MYSCRIPT.js', array('weight' => 25));
    //...
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As @Clive mentioned it is because your `JS` order load is wrong(your JS loaded before than views JS)
I suggest you instead add JS in `hook_init` put it in `hook_form_alter` or in `hook_page_preprocess`

```
drupal_add_js( drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME').'/assets/js/MYSCRIPT.js',array(
            'type' => 'file',
            'scope' => 'footer',
            'weight' => 100,
        )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Zhilevan, it seems you arrived after the battle :-) This is already what I did (`hook_init` and so on), if you read question and comments. If you wish to complete your answer explaining I had to copy/paste the whole `Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.viewsScrollTop` in my js, then add a heavy weight to that script, I'll be glad to mark it as accepted for further researches...

Comment: @Kojo I suggest please add it because maybe somebody else have the same problem and it can help them ;)

Comment: Zhilevan, after reading again your answer, I understand you suggest another solution. It might work, but I solved issue with Clive's one. I will post it in order to help. Thanks a lot anyway.